# git: local branch contains changes that are committed&pushed in master but not remote branch

Tags: git, github

I forked a project A and clone the forked repo on my machine.

Then I worked on "master" and added a new file "random.txt" into a folder and then committed and pushed it to my forked repo on github.

Later, I need to work on another branch "heroku" for a specific deployment tweak, I ran

`git checkout -b heroku origin/heroku`

and then I discovered that the local "heroku" branch contains the new "random.txt" file, which I did not expect since on github, the remote branch "heroku" does not have this file.

I ran "git status" and it says there is no change at local. I'm confused. I'd like to understand why the local branch is different remote branch?

and I'd like to further update the remote repo "heroku" to have the "random.txt". Since "git status" reports no changes in the branch, i have noting to commit and push. What I can do?

Comment: origin - it's a remote repo local name.

Comment: Are you sure you're on the 'heroku' branch ? And what does git log say ?

Comment: I'm sure it is the "heroku" branch. On branch "heroku" , the "git log" shows previous commitments by the original author.

Comment: Check the `.gitignore` the file might be ignored somehow.

Comment: I double checked the .gitignore, it does not include the .txt or its parent folder